IronPdf Digital Signature - Error while retrieving length of signature contents
I am trying to add a digital certificate to a PDF using IronPdf and get an error:
Unhandled exception. IronSoftware.Exceptions.IronSoftwareNativeException: Error while retrieving digital signatures: 'Error while retrieving length of signature contents'.
I have looked at the IronPdf documentation and followed their instructions, including the Adobe instructions to create a certificate (link found on IronPdf documentation).
I spoke with customer support and did not receive a resolution to this issue. I have also tried using older versions of their NuGet packages with the same results.
I am unfamiliar with digital signatures and was hoping someone could shed some light on the "length of signature contents" of this error message. Maybe I am not creating the pfx file correctly?

Code used:
var signature = new PdfSignature(certPath, certPassword)
{
    SignatureDate = DateTime.Now,                
    SigningContact = "support@ironsoftware.com",
    SigningLocation = "Chicago, USA",
    SigningReason = "To show how to sign a PDF"
};

signature.SignPdfFile(pdfPath);


I'm from Iron Software support team.
Could you contact the support again? I will handle the issue.

Will do. I will also create a support ticket
